# How to resolve bycrypt dependency issue in module.

Tags: node.js, npm, bcrypt

I keep getting this issue: 
[snip of my issue][1]

I'm teaching myself node and am trying to make a CRUD RESTful application in my spare time. I'm working off this book:
https://leanpub.com/mean-machine.

For the past 3 days I've been stuck with this issue. It is specifically concerning the `bcrypt-node.js` . It's job is to hash passwords. Some things I have tried.

- Downloaded python 3.5 as I got errors saying the runtime was needed to execute.
- Setting python environment variable in PATH
- npm uninstall and install.
- Tried creating a new project, same issues cropped up.
- npm clear cache
- Since it is an old version of the `bcrypt-node.js` module changed the version in package.json from "0.0.3" to "0.0.5". I thought it could be a bug. Unlikely as that is.

I'm very new to node.js so I feel like I'm doing something silly that I just cannot see. Also I don't understand a lot of the information the command line is providing me. Thank you in advance.

EDIT 1: 
[Picture of my code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bATbR.png)

Edit. (For future visitors) I needed to pay more attention to the various dependencies and a further understanding of JS in general to utitlise the power of Node.js, which is something I didn't do. Also recommended is a good understanding of Express.

A deeper understand of the npm is needed.

Comment: There's no such [bcrypt-node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt-node.js) package. Did you mean [bcrypt-nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt-nodejs)?

Comment: Yes! Sorry my bad. damn typo.

Comment: Can you update your post with code, please?

Comment: Hi I added a snip of my code.

Comment: Are you using unix like or windows ? 32 or 64 bits ? And show your require of bcrypt

Comment: Using Windows 10 operating system on my machine. The CLI I am using is mingw-w64.

The hash is generated in a separate file that you have to create to fulfill in order for Mongoose to work correctly,the Mongoose file has some metadata and variables that consume the information provided by the installed packages. 

The hash is created there. Do you want to see that code as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix through trial and error and some googling.

In case any one looks up this again in the future I entered: 
`npm install node-gyp -g && npm cache clean && rm -rf node_modules && npm install`into the command line and it appeared to fix the issue when I ran `nodemon server.js`

Fingers crossed it does not crop up again.

If someone would like to explain to me what exactly was the problem I had I would really appreciate it. I have a feeling a module or dependency wasn't installed correctly?

EDIT 1. Furthermore configure the PATH in your environment variables. 
ie I created a path for python in the command line
PATH python = C:\Python27\python.exe  & another PATH for MongoDB
i.e C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin